# Installing Windows SBS 2011 Proliant on another Proliant server

Tags: windows-sbs-2011

I have an unused copy of SBS 2011 Standard which was never installed on the HP Proliant server it came with. Question is, am I able to install this on a another HP Proliant server? On the product key label it says `Win SBS Std ROK 2011 1-4CPU 5-CAL`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROK is just [Reseller Option Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/salesmarketing/Pages/reseller-option-kit.aspx#fbid=y2aAhJMb5_X), it's usually OEM & unassigned until installed (and licensed affixed) to that machine.

Once you install it on the new HP, it lives/dies with that machine.

On another note, 2011 is end of life, and support for each product ends [independently](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle?p1=15817)